# how add a group to another group in linux

Tags: boot, networking, dual-boot, server

i want to add a group to another group in linux
for example i have a group called love , i want to add it to another group called  sky ,
i have experience with linux , i want to someone with a lot of linux commands

Comment: Your second paragraph has nothing to do with the first. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

You can not add groups as members of other groups, only users.